# TSQL: Return only if 1 row exists based on where clause

Tags: t-sql

Lets say I have a table with 3 columns with following values:

```
   ticketid     indexid    type  
    ---          ---       ---
    100           191       0
    100           192       2
    100           193       4
    200           194       0
    300           195       1
    300           196       0
```

My desired output:

```
   ticketid     indexid    type  
    ---          ---       ---
    200           194       0
```

I only want those rows which have:

1) only 1 row (based on ticketid) in the table

2) have type = (0,2,4)

This is the query I have which is not working:

```
select distinct ticketid from tab1 where type not in (1,3) group by ticketid having count(indexid) = 1
```

When I run the above query I am still getting tickets which have more than 1 rows. How can I fix this?

Comment: u dont need the distinct keyword, since you're grouping by ticketid.

Comment: and you should count(1) or count(ticketID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the grouping in a subquery. Then in the main query pull all of the columns.

```
select ticketid, indexid, type
  from tab1
 where type in (0,2,4)
   and ticketid in (
    select ticketid from tab1 group by ticketid having count(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: My answer was prematurely submitted.  I've finished my answer, and corrected a typo in the original data that I seeded my table variable with.  New answer provides requested result set.

Answer (score 1):

you need to group the data and do a count on each group. For ex)

```
create table tab1 
(
    ticketid int,
    indexid int,
    type int
)



insert into tab1
values 
( 100,           191,       0),
(100,           192,       2),
(   100,           193 ,      4),
(  200  ,        194   ,    0),
( 300  ,         195 ,      1),
(300  ,         196  ,     0)




select * 
from tab1 


select ticketid 
from tab1 
--exclude tickets that contains the invalid types
where ticketID NOT IN (

    --get tickets that does not contain the valid types
    select ticketID
    from tab1
    where type NOT IN (0,2,4)
)
group by ticketid 
having count(1) = 1
```

Comment: i've just updated my post. can you please check again?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I'm still getting rows which have multiple counts for ticketids

Answer (score 1):

I've edited this answer because I misread the original requirements.

```
DECLARE  @tab1 TABLE (TicketID INT, IndexID INT, Type Int)

INSERT 
  INTO   @tab1 (TicketID, IndexID, Type)
VALUES  (100,191,0)
       ,(100,192,2)
       ,(100,193,4)
       ,(200,194,0)
       ,(300,195,1)
       ,(300,196,0)


SELECT   T.TicketID
        ,T.IndexID
        ,T.Type
  FROM  (
         SELECT  TicketID
                ,COUNT(IndexID) AS CountOfIndex
                ,CASE WHEN Type IN (0,2,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ValidType
           FROM  @tab1
          GROUP
             BY  TicketID
                ,CASE WHEN Type IN (0,2,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        ) DATA1
  JOIN   @tab1 T
    ON   T.TicketID = DATA1.TicketID
 WHERE   DATA1.CountOfIndex = 1
GROUP BY T.TicketID
        ,T.IndexID
        ,T.Type
 HAVING MIN(DATA1.ValidType) = 1
```

This provides the following results:

```
TicketID    IndexID     Type
200         194         0
```

This query uses a derived table to first find the number of IndexID values based on the repeating TicketID values, while also determining if the Type column value is valid for inclusion in the final output.

The outer query then looks for a the Tickets that have a CountOfIndex = 1, and the minimum value for the Type = 1 (eliminating any records where the TicketID was associated with an invalid Type value).

It may not be the cleanest solution, but I believe that this code highlights the thinking behind classifying wanted and unwanted data, and how to filter the unwanted data out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `ticketid+indexid` is unique, you can do this:

```
select ticketid 
from tab1 
where type not in (1,3) 
group by ticketid 
having count(distinct indexid) = 1
```

(which is the just your original query reformatted and the `distinct` keyword moved to the correct place)

Comment: I'm getting 200 and 300 as well using your query :( I want only 200 since 300 has 2 entries in the table above

Comment: please update the qustion with sample data and expected output.Thsi kind of chit chat is what you can expect when question is not accurate